# Flex auto margin not working in IE10/11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I have a complex layout where I center various elements vertically and horizontally with flexbox.

The last element then has `margin-right:auto;` applied to push the elements left (and negate centering them).

This works correctly everywhere except on IE10/11 and has been driving me crazy.

**HTML/CSS sample:**

```css
#container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#second-item {
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* just some colors - not important */
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#container > div {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='first-item'>first item</div>
  <div id='second-item'>second item</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrWVbR

You'll see two items on the screen that should be left-aligned on the side of the red parent (i.e. they should both be centered, but the last item has `margin-right:auto;` applied and is filling the entire line, pushing the other item and itself on the side) - this is the correct behaviour. Except in IE10/11 where both items are incorrectly centered i.e. the second item's `margin-right:auto;` is ignored.

Any IE/flexbox experts out there that have encountered something like this before?

Comment: Hi, margin auto is problematic in IE11 (See other answer for more details on why.) Fix: Consider using align-items or justify-content.

Comment: Probably you forgot to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 78):

**This appears to be an IE bug.**

According to the flexbox specification:

> [**8.1. Aligning with auto margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.
>
> Note: If free space is distributed to auto margins, the alignment properties will have no effect in that dimension because the margins will have stolen all the free space left over after flexing.

In other words, auto margins take precedence over `justify-content`.

In fact, if an element has auto margins applied, then keyword alignment properties such as `justify-content` and `align-self` have no effect (because the auto margins have taken all the space).

Your code works as expected in Chrome and Firefox because those browsers are in compliance with the spec.

IE10 and IE11 appear to not be in compliance. They are not applying the auto margin as defined in the spec.

*(Note that IE10 is built on a [previous version of the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).)*

---

**Solutions**

*Method #1: Use auto margins only*

If `justify-content` is removed, auto margins work fine in IE10/11.
So don't use `justify-content`. Use auto margins all the way through. ([See examples of alignment with auto margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)).

*Method #2: Use an invisible spacer div*

Create a third div with `visibility: hidden` and `flex-grow:1`. This will naturally shift `#first-item` and `#second-item` to the left edge, with no need for auto margins.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
#third-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* just some colors - not important */
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
#container > div {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='first-item'>first item</div>
  <div id='second-item'>second item</div>
  <div id='third-item'>third item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just remove the auto margins and keep justify-content?

Comment: Solution for me was to switch to `align-self: center;` instead of `margin: 0 auto;` on flex child elements.

Comment: How come the `visibility` of the "filler" `#third-item` is being set to `hidden` ?

Comment: This answer is mentioned in [the bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins).